# Diagonalization with complex eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, diagonalization

Given $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -4 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ find a matrix C of the form $ C = \begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$ and a matrix P such that $A = PCP^{-1}$.  Then factor the C matrix as a product of a scaling matrix of the form $rI_2$ and a rotation matrix of the form $\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\varphi) & -\sin(\varphi) \\ \sin(\varphi) & \cos(\varphi) \end{bmatrix}$.

I can get everything correct except for the factoring C part.  I get the angle being $-\pi / 2$, but I get the wrong C unless I use $r = -2,$ but I thought that isn't allowed.

*edit: The theorem in my textbook:

Let A be a 2x2 matrix with a complex eigenvalue $\lambda = a - bi \ (b\neq0)$ and an associated eigenvector $\vec{v}$ in $\mathbb{C^2}$.  Then
$$ A = PCP^{-1}, \ \text{where} \ P = \begin{bmatrix} Re(\vec{v}) & Im(\vec{v}) \end{bmatrix} and C = \begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Write $R$ for the rotation matrix, so that $C=rIR$.  Taking determinants,
$$\det(C)=r^2$$
because $\det(R)=1$.  But $\det(C)=\det(A)=4$, so we can take $r=\pm2$.  Depending which $C$ you have chosen (there are two possibilities) you will then get $\phi=\pm\pi/2$.

Comment: I edited my original post to include the theorem in my text.  What confuses me is that it specifies the eigenvalue with a negative imaginary part.  So when I choose $-2i,$ I have to use a negative $r,$ which I thought was not allowed, but you say it is.

Comment: In principle you can take the eigenvalues either way round, but if the question asks you to do it one specific way then I guess that's what you do.  Though I don't know why they would ask that ;-)